# okHttp Get Android issue

Tags: android, get, okhttp

Im trying to insert values in a server data base with GET,
I already did it with POST using OkHttp but after checking the web service **I have to change it to GET.**

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

JsonArray form = new JsonArray();
JsonObject item = new JsonObject();

item.addProperty("table", "images");
item.addProperty("operation", "insert");

JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
JsonObject paramItem = new JsonObject();
paramItem.addProperty("color_id", colorId);
paramItem.addProperty("name", name);
params.add(paramItem);
item.add("params", params);
item.addProperty("transactionCompleted", true);
form.add(item);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MIME_JSON, new Gson().toJson(form));
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        .url("http://www.example.com/webservice/?value=")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

                okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

                    }
                });
```

**What to I have to change in my code to make this a GET REQUEST?**

*This is the query that I have to perform*

```
http://example.com/webservice/?value=
[{
     "table": "images",
      "operation": "insert",
      "params": [
        {
          "color_id": 2 ,        
          "name": "yellow" 
        }
      ],
      "transactionCompleted": true
    }]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To send a json object you need a request body.

Okhttp library has a file called HttpMethod.java where you can find these functions:

```
public static boolean requiresRequestBody(String method) {
    return method.equals("POST")
        || method.equals("PUT")
        || method.equals("PATCH");
}

public static boolean permitsRequestBody(String method) {
    return requiresRequestBody(method)
        || method.equals("DELETE"); // Permitted as spec is ambiguous.
}
```

As you can see, GET method is not permitted to have a body, so apparently you cannot send this json via GET method using Okhttp library.

Comment: mhm so what can I use?

Comment: @kinsell I think you should try another library which allows bodies in GET requests, if any. But generally don't use GET requests with bodies.

Comment: I cant find any example for GET request with bodies, I can't even do it with HttpUrlConnection, Do you know any libs that can do this?